# fast gps fix without SIM on Mobile

Tags: android, gps

Is it possible to get fast GPS fix without a SIM card on my android mobile.

Assuming I know my actual GPS coordinates (from another device), will it help in getting a fast fix. If yes, how do I use that.

Other option, is it possible to get the A-GPS info from another mobile and pass the same to the intended mobile using bluetooth?

Or, is there any other approach?